# Question regarding removal of a perfect matching in bridgeless graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, connectedness, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Suppose a connected bridgeless graph has a perfect matching. If we delete the edges forming the perfect matching, then will the graph be still connected?

Will the graph be still bridgeless too?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: $C_4$ is a simple counterexample to both of these claims.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyDover :)